# VB.Net, ComboBox when lostfocus => Error : invalid argument value of 0 is not valid for index

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, combobox

I m working on a VB.Net using Framework 3.5, i need a specific autocomplete for the combo, in that way i m using a BindingSource that can i use its "Filter" Property

```
    Dim m_bsCommune As New BindingSource
    m_bsCommune.DataSource = m_dtCommune
    cboCommune.DataSource = m_bsCommune
```

Then, i implemented the event "TextUpdate" of combo :

```
    Private Sub cboCommune_TextUpdate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboCommune.TextUpdate

    Dim cboValue As String = cboCommune.Text

    m_bsCommune.Filter = String.Format("CODE_COM Like '%{0}%'", cboCommune.Text)
    cboCommune.Text = cboValue
    cboCommune.Select(cboCommune.Text.Length, 0)
    cboCommune.DroppedDown = True

End Sub
```

The filter works fine, but in the case i tape a value that does not exist in the combo, and when i try to move to another control, or i click outside the combo i get the error :

> "invalid argument value of 0 is not valid for index"

I tried to manage this error on the events "LostFocus, GotFocus" but the error is generated befor those two events !

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the line of the error? Cleary you are acessing an invalid index on 
`m_bsCommune.Filter = String.Format("CODE_COM Like '%{0}%'", cboCommune.Text)` or `cboCommune.Select(cboCommune.Text.Length, 0)` try to verify the lenght of `cbocommune.Text`

Comment: Thanks for the remarque :)
When i add a break point to the function "cboCommune_TextUpdate" its wokrs fine, the problme occure when the control lost the focus

Comment: I've tried to manage this error on the events "LostFocus, GotFocus", but i think thant there is another event happend before those two "LostFocus, GotFocus", what do think ?

Comment: Have you verified the  error callstack? To see in what method the erros occurs? are any other combobox events that you are using?
This is just a guess but i think the errros is when you update your list since you found nothing...

Comment: Thanks again,
yes i m using KeyPressed Event, but i check if its Keys.Tab before
I think the error callstack show only the developped methodes, but here, in my case the problem is linked to something not managed !
Thats what i think ! what do u think ?